# I parse text from richTextBox how can i clear " and , from the string?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the code:

```
public static string ParseText(string text, int startPos, int endPos)
{
    string images = "";

    if (startPos >= 0 && endPos > startPos)
    {
        images = text.Substring(startPos + 1, endPos - startPos - 1);
        images.Replace(',',' ');
    }
    return images;
}
```

Im using this part to clean/remove `,` and `"`

```
entries = images.Split(new[] { ',' });
for (var i = 0; i < entries.Length; i++)
{
    entries[i] = entries[i].Replace("\"", "");
}
```

For example if i have this part of text:

```
"http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx?jaar=-6&type=europa.cld&datum=201311221800&cultuur=en-GB&continent=europa","http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx?jaar=-6&type=europa.cld&datum=201311222100&cultuur=en-GB&continent=europa","http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx?jaar=-6&type=europa.cld&datum=201311230000&cultuur=en-GB&continent=europa","http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx?jaar=-6&type=europa.cld&datum=201311230300&cultuur=en-GB&continent=europa","http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx?jaar=-6&type=europa.cld&datum=201311230600&cultuur=en-GB&continent=europa","http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx?jaar=-6&type=europa.cld&datum=201311230900&cultuur=en-GB&continent=europa","
```

And its longer...But in this example i want to remove all the " and ,
If im using the code as it is now the result is:

Im getting only the first link:

```
http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx?jaar=-6&type=europa.cld&datum=201311221800&cultuur=en-GB&continent=europa
```

If i remove the lines:

```
entries = images.Split(new[] { ',' });
for (var i = 0; i < entries.Length; i++)
    entries[i] = entries[i].Replace("\"", "");
```

Then i will see all the text but with `,` and `"`

What is wrong with cleaning the `,` and `"`?

Why it show me only the first text part and not all the rest ?

Comment: You should take a look at [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: RE _getting only the first link_: Can you share the code that consumes what `ParseText` returns?

Comment: Updated my question i changed my code this is the code im using now but the replace im using is not removing the " and , chars

Comment: It should leave a space/s where there was , or " but it dosent do anything.

Comment: Look for a dedicated CSV parser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

strings in C# are immutable.

```
images.Replace(',', '');
```

... by design does not affect `images`.  What you need is:

```
images = images.Replace(',', ' ');
```

Perhaps you want them as a joined string?

```
var result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, images.Split(new[] { ',' }).Select(e => e.Replace("\"", "")));
```

---

If I'm understanding your comment correctly,

```
// could easily be an extension method
public static string ReplacingChars(string source, char[] toReplace, string withThis)
{
    return string.Join(withThis, source.Split(toReplace, StringSplitOptions.None));
}

// usage:
images = ReplacingChars(images, new [] {',', '"'}, " ");
```

Comment: Austin this line you gave me give error on the last two '' Error 1 Empty character literal

Comment: Now its working Austin but i wanted to add options for now two options to or three. 1. like you did now joined. 2. remove only " or only , and leave spaces there. There must be a way to remove this chars or any other chars and leave spaces instead. Maybe making a small method for that for replacing chars.

Comment: Perfect thanks now i can select between Join or Replace. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using string.Replace(). See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information.

e.g.

```
images.Replace(',','');
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me!

```
string ParseText(string input)
{
    // Replace quotes with nothing at all...
    var noQuotes = input.Replace("\"", "");
    // Replace commas with, I dunno, "whatever you want"... 
    // If you want to just get rid of the commas, you could use "",
    // or if you want a space, " "
    return input.Replace("," "whatever you want");
}
```

Comment: Ok i will try it but Jeff then im using this method in form1 by this way: richTextBox2.Text = Parse_Text.ParseText(richTextBox1.Text, positionToSearch, currentChar); but now this method return IEnumerable<string> and not string so i mgetting error on that in form1

Comment: Editted... the `positionToSearch` and `currentChar` stuff is not related to actually removing characters, so I've left it out of my answer.